# rails - Prefetching records to process in a queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an active record relation that is defined like this:

```
contacts = Contact.where("status = 'waiting'")
```

Then, I do the following:

```
if contacts

    batch_id = randomStringOfLength(32)

    #Set to processing
    contacts.update_all(status: 'processing', batch_id: batch_id)

    #TODO: Is this the best way to do this? 
    contacts = Contact.where("batch_id = ?", batch_id)

    contacts.each do |contact|

         executeFor(contact)

    end
end
```

As you can see, I'm having to update the records with a specific `batch_id` in order to later be able to fetch them.

This is because my first instance of contacts doesn't actually fetch the records. The first database call is the update to status `processing` and then fetching them by batch_id allows me to run the each loop.

Is there a better way to do this? Although I have indexed `batch_id` I think there might be a better way in rails.

If I don't update the `batch_id` and remove the line to fetch by `batch_id`, then the `.each` will not return anything because the status was previously updated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this question related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363743 ?

Comment: @StephanePaquet not at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need a `batch_id` in your database you can write the following:

```
contacts = Contact.where(status: 'waiting')
if contacts

    #Set to processing
    contacts.update_all(status: 'processing')

    #TODO: Is this the best way to do this? 
    contacts = Contact.where(status: 'processing')

    contacts.each do |contact|
         executeFor(contact)
    end
end
```

And this option may even be a little bit faster:

```
if Contact.where(status: 'waiting').update_all(status: 'processing') > 0
    contacts = Contact.where(status: 'processing')

    contacts.each do |contact|
         executeFor(contact)
    end
end
```

Do not forget to check your indexes on your database. status needs one.

Keeping `batch_id`:

```
batch_id = randomStringOfLength(32)
if Contact.where(status: 'waiting').update_all(status: 'processing', batch_id: batch_id) > 0
    contacts = Contact.where(batch_id: batch_id)

    contacts.each do |contact|
         executeFor(contact)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey Stephane, thank you for the answer. However, this could arise an issue if another queue is currently running. I can't assume that all records that are processing belong to the current batch. Makes sense?