# rails - updating active record relation with multiple changed properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an active record relation defined like this:

```
contacts = Contact.where("status = 'waiting'")
```

I then run an `.each` loop and change properties of contacts depending on some logic.

I don't want to do a `save!` on each individual contact... how can I better save the entire contacts relation after the loop?

```
contacts.each do |contact|

        //Change properties of contact here

end
```

How do I save the newly updates contacts activerecord relation after it contains its new properties?

The most efficient way can't be doing a contact by contact save.

Comment: Could your logic be implemented in SQL? So we can use ActiveRecord and do it at once in the database without looping on the objects.

Comment: No. Too many things are happening inside of the each. Do you think if I have an updated activerecord relation that then i can do the update in sql? Sorry if that's what you meant. Please let me know @StephanePaquet

Comment: I was thinking of grouping updates by types so you can use UPDATE command. Something like `UPDATE table SET fields with new values WHERE conditions`

Comment: please share what you exactly need - "i've some internal logic" is not enough, others can't estimate your intentions unless you write.

Comment: @marmeladze what happens inside the scope of the each loop is not relevant to this question. The part that falls within the scope is that each contact is getting assigned a different property/id whatever you want to refer to it as. Now-how do i update a contacts active record relation with new properties.... i don't see how the contents of the loop other than what I described is of any relevance

Answer (score 1):

update_all saves you from doing the loop and do the save for you,  here is the documentation.
https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: The loop isn't only to update fields. I also use attributes of the contact and modify different contacts with different attributes. This doesn't work. Thank though

Comment: Can you share the code so we can better understand what you're doing in this loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). As you said, you could assign all the new values for each contacts and finally save the changes in a bulk manner with this [upsert](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/On-Duplicate-Key-Update).